# Unable to extract prebuilt virtualbox with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, 7-zip

I went to this site, http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/

to download prebuilt Virtual Box, with IE 10, Windows 8.

The instructions say extract with 7-zip.

When I try to extract, it asks for password. There is no documentation on password to extract the file.

This is only for 90-day trial.

[image]

I tried using build number 20141027 and Passw0rd! as password

It took practically the whole day to download this yesterday, and now I'm having difficulty extracting it.

Kindly assist.

I left password blank, and I get this error

[image]

Comment: The file isn't password protected. Could it be you're confused by 7-zip's password field? You can ignore that. Just click on "OK" and leave the password field blank.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 I tried and it says `Can not open file`

Comment: Your extraction menu looks rather outdated. It lacks quite a few options. Did you make sure to use an up to date version?

Comment: The error message is rather unspecific. May be a third party program blocks access to the file (AV-Software for example), or your 7-zip version is too outdated or it was damaged during the download among countless other things. I uploaded a screenshot with checksums for the file so that you can at least check whether the file was downloaded correctly: http://abload.de/img/checksums1yui3.png

Comment: There isn't a password.  I just downloaded it.  It does not require a password.  Use WinZip, WinRAR, or a current version of 7Zip.  Verify the the file is complete, because, as I said there isn't a password.

Comment: @Ramhound I downloaded Winzip, and I still get error. Will re-download and check again

Comment: You need to verify the file is even complete based on the error I place your chances of that being the case at basically zero.